# Incorrect monitor colours

Tags: monitor, colors

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 and my monitor had a problem where Green is the bright colour, there's no way to change it in the monitor settings, so when I was using WinXP (I'm new in here) I changed the green to lower using Video Driver settings, in here (ubuntu) I don't know exactly how I would change the green colour to low, so my "black" would be seem has a real black, no green.
Thanks for reading. Sorry for bad English.

Comment: You might be able to adjust it with the `xgamma` tool  (in particular the `-ggamma` option).  I'm not sure how well this would help with the green brightness for black pixels though.

Comment: @JamesHenstridge, works fine, thanks. But you commented in here, so how may I give you the best answer?

Comment: Glad it helped.  I've added an answer based on the suggestion, along with some tips to apply the setting each time you log in and how to handle multiple monitors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adjust the individual colour [gamma correction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction) settings of your screen using the `xgamma` tool.  Running it with no arguments will print the current settings:

```
$ xgamma
-> Red  1.000, Green  1.000, Blue  1.000
```

You can adjust the green gamma value with a command like:

```
$ xgamma -ggamma 0.75
```

If you are using a multi-monitor set up and want to adjust the gamma of individual outputs, you can do so with the `xrandr` tool instead:

```
$ xrandr --output $OUTPUT --gamma $RED:$GREEN:$BLUE
```

In this command, `$OUTPUT` is one of the outputs listed when you run `xrandr` with no arguments.  Note also that `xrandr` treats the gamma mapping as going in the reverse direction, so you will need to provide the inverse of the values you'd provide to `xgamma` (e.g. passing 2.0 to `xgamma` is equivalent to passing 0.5 to `xrandr`).

Both of these options will not survive an X server restart, so once you've got some values you're happy with consider putting them in a shell script (perhaps in `~/bin`), and then adding that script as a startup application.